# Where should I ask a developer question about Google's web store?

Tags: support, questions, site-recommendation

Where should I ask a question about Google's web store? I want to know if a Google developer fee is necessary in order to upload a web extension to Google's web store.
**Stack Overflow** seems the right site but it's about code and this is not code; **Super User** is also not an option as there is not a single chatroom regarding that.

Comment: To add to this now that you’ve asked your question on SO and I’ve read it: Glorfindel’s answer below refers to *technical questions* about a *technical hurdle* you’ve asked in a *devlopment* context. Your question is about a *commercial model* and how to avoid fees. That’s off-topic on SO and across the network.  Despite the fact that we have a large audience here most likely to know this kind of stuff, SE is *not* designed to “pick the brains” of experts on any topic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you're talking about the [Chrome Web Store](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/category/extensions). Since it arguably counts as a "software tool commonly used by programmers", as mentioned in the [Stack Overflow Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and it's "a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development", I think Stack Overflow is the right place for your question.

It might have already been asked before; there are currently 415 questions tagged [chrome-web-store](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/chrome-web-store) already. Maybe you can find your answer there.

Note that only a few select topics have a dedicated chatroom; Stack Overflow might have a few dozen but there are many more tags/topics which are on-topic but don't have their own chatroom.